# gmplot Marker does not work after it marks 256 points

Tags: python-3.x, gmplot

I am trying to mark a bunch of points on the map with gmplot and observed that after a certain point it stops marking and wipes out all the previously marked points. I debugged the gmplot.py module and saw that when the length of points array exceeds 256 this is happening without giving any error and warning.

```
self.points = [] on gmplot.py
```

Since I am very new to Python and OOPs concept, is there a way to override this and mark more than 256 points?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter.Scatter` or `gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter.Marker`. I used either and was able to get `465` points for a project that I was working on. Is it possible it is an API key issue for you?

partial snippet of my code

```
import gmplot
import pandas as pd
# df is the database with Lat, Lon and formataddress columns
# change to list, not sure you need to do this.  I think you can cycle through
# directly using iterrows.  I have not tried that though
latcollection=df['Lat'].tolist()
loncollection=df['Lon'].tolist()
addcollection=df['formataddress'].tolist()
# center map with the first co-ordinates
gmaps2 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(latcollection[0],loncollection[0],13,apikey='yourKey')
for i in range(len(latcollection)):
    gmaps2.marker(latcollection[i],loncollection[i],color='#FF0000',c=None,title=str(i)+' '+ addcollection[i])
gmaps2.draw(newdir + r'\laplot_marker_full.html')
```

I could hover over the 465th point since I knew approximately where it was and I was able to get the title with `str(464) <formataddress(464)>`, since my array is indexed from 0

Make sure you check the GitHub site to modify your gmplot file, in case you are working with windows.